# How can I fix or troubleshoot my Internet connection problem?

Tags: internet, connection-issues, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8

I am using a Sony Ericsson Xperia running Android 2.3.4. When I try to access online applications like Gmail, Facebook, Android Market etc. I get an error that says `No connection, retry?` or `No data service provider`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Are you using mobile data or WiFi? Have you tried both?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this isn't a DNS issue.  In the browser try navigating to the website by its IP address as opposed to the name.

On your computer open command prompt and type in `ping google.com` and press enter.  The 4 numbers 1-3 digits long separated by dots is the IP address (e.g. 74.125.113.106).  Now on the phone open up the browser, and in the  navigation bar type in "http://" followed by the IP address you got from your computer (e.g. `http://74.125.113.106`) and press the Go key.  If the website loads - your phone has a bad DNS entry.  The Market has several [apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=dns%20changer&c=apps) for changing phone's default DNS.